# Matplotlib grid xaxis in daily interval

Tags: matplotlib, grid

I have a .csv file with data every 10 minutes that looks like this:

```
15/12/2012 13:00,20.83,23.06,23.07,23.12,22.73,22.13,22.79,22.62,13.5,47
15/12/2012 13:10,20.93,23.1,23.1,23.16,22.72,22.18,22.84,22.74,13.5,45.3
15/12/2012 13:20,21.05,23.14,23.12,23.23,22.56,22.23,22.91,22.83,13.4,44.7
15/12/2012 13:30,21.16,23.16,23.07,23.26,22.45,22.23,22.94,22.91,13.3,36.1
15/12/2012 13:40,21.17,23.2,23.06,23.29,22.34,22.24,22.97,22.99,13.3,28.2
15/12/2012 13:50,21.15,23.22,23.06,23.33,22.18,22.24,22.93,23.04,13.3,28.2
15/12/2012 14:00,21.15,23.24,23.07,23.35,22.12,22.28,23,23.1,13.3,25.6
...
```

I would like to plot a graph and have a grid in the x-axis in a daily interval. But I only get a grid in a random distance. I did:

```
MeasurementData = pd.read_csv('/Users/Silvia/Dropbox/TH/Mediciones/TH_Temperaturas.csv',index_col='Date_Time')
MeasurementData.plot(figsize=(15,10))
```

I have been trying with these comands:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%D"))
```

But I couldn't do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your index is a `DatetimeIndex` rather than an object-index. This can be achieved by passing `parse_dates='Date_Time'` to the `pd.read_csv` function, like this:

```
MeasurementData = pd.read_csv('/Users/Silvia/Dropbox/TH/Mediciones/TH_Temperaturas.csv',index_col='Date_Time',parse_dates='Date_Time')
```

Then you should be able to set the tickmarks at each day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I run it and I have been trying both but it is not working.

Comment: @SilviaDomingo Updated the code, I believe your index was not a `DatetimeIndex`. You can specify that the `'Date_Time'` column consists of `Datetime` objects by including `parse_dates='Date_Time'` in the `pd.read_csv` function call.